# How do I pick folders only, using TOpenFileName?

Tags: delphi, windows-7

I need to be able to select folders using the native Windows 7 open dialog, ie. not by using `SelectDirectory()`.

I currently have a procedure that calls up a dialog using `TOpenFileName`, which works quite well.

Is there a hidden flag that I can use to ensure the dialog only allows the selection of a folder, where the button changes to "Select Folder"?

**Note:** I don't want to use Delphi's standard TFileOpenDialog. I would prefer to stick to my own functions for this.

Comment: Why not use the `TFileOpenDialog` with `fdoPickFolders`? That will give you a native Windows 7 open dialog, in 'select directory' mode.

Comment: I can't imagine why you don't want to use `TFileOpenDialog`. It's the answer

Comment: Like I said, I've chosen not to do that as I already have a function of my own that I'd like to be able to use for this. Was hoping there'd be an `OFN_` flag, but there isn't.

Comment: It's rather pointless to ask a question and then rule out the answer. -1

Comment: @Michael: IIRC, the `OFN_` constants are used with [the old way](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646927(v=vs.85).aspx) of displaying common dialogs. Since Windows Vista, you should use the [new approach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776913(v=vs.85).aspx), which adds new features. I think directory browsing is one of those. So you need a complete rewrite. Or use `TFileOpenDialog`.

Comment: @David, it would be an answer if I asked how to do it using `TFileOpenDialog`, or from a general point of view. I do hope there's a way to do it. (I have a funny feeling there isn't, considering how the class is named: `TOpen**Filename**`)

Comment: OFN_ is for `GetOpenFileName` and `GetSaveFileName`. They don't support folder browsing. The new Vista dialog, `IFileDialog` does support folder browsing. And that's what is wrapped by `TFileOpenDialog`. So, you have asked a question and then stated that the one and only answer is not acceptable!

Comment: The standard **Delphi** `TFileOpenDialog` is actually the standard **Windows** dialog, which (as @David keeps telling you) is the proper way to do this on Win7. If you don't want the answers, it's probably better not to post the question here.

Comment: You've made it clear what answer you want. There it is!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a hidden flag that I can use to ensure the dialog only allows the selection of a folder, where the button changes to "Select Folder"?

No there is not. You need to use `TFileOpenDialog` which wraps `IFileDialog` which is the system component that provides this functionality.